# How would you have a range of movement within a class in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I have blitted 4 zombies to the screen in pygame. First, the zombies will wander in a specific region (let us say a 10 x 10 area). And when the player enters any one of the zombie's areas, the zombie should target the player.

```
import pygame, random, os
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

scr_width = 1020
scr_height = 510
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((scr_width, scr_height))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

images = {}
path = 'Desktop/Files/Dungeon Minigame/'
filenames = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.png')]
for name in filenames:
    imagename = os.path.splitext(name)[0]
    images[imagename] = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(path, name))

pygame.display.set_caption('Dungeon Minigame')

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Times_New_Roman', 27)

white = [240, 240, 240]

fps = 60
lives = 3
score = 0

playerX = 510
playerY = 220
playerxchange = 0
playerychange = 0

def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(images['r_knight'], (playerX, playerY))

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(8, 800)
        self.y = random.randint(8, 440)
        self.moveX = 0
        self.moveY = 0

    def move(self):
        self.speed = 3
    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(images['r_zombie'], (self.x, self.y))

def enemy(x, y):
    screen.blit(images['r_zombie'], (x, y))

enemy_list = []
for i in range(4):
    new_enemy = Enemy()
    enemy_list.append(new_enemy)

while True:

    screen.blit(images['background'], (0, 0))

    score_text = font.render('Score: ' + str(score), True, white)
    lives_text = font.render('Lives: ', True, white)

    screen.blit(score_text, (20, 20))
    screen.blit(lives_text, (840, 20))

    onpress = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    screen.blit(images['r_knight'], (playerX, playerY))

    if lives == 3:
        screen.blit(images['triple_heart'], (920, 0))

    if lives == 2:
        screen.blit(images['double_heart'], (920, 0))

    if lives == 1:
        screen.blit(images['single_heart'], (920, 0))

    if lives <= 0:
        screen.blit(images['triple_empty_heart'], (920, 0))
        if lives < 0:
            lives = 0

    if onpress[pygame.K_a]:
        playerX -= 3
        screen.blit(images['l_knight'], (playerX, playerY))

    if onpress[pygame.K_w]:
        playerY -= 3
        screen.blit(images['l_knight'], (playerX, playerY))

    if onpress[pygame.K_d]:
        playerX += 3
        screen.blit(images['r_knight'], (playerX, playerY))

    if onpress[pygame.K_s]:
        playerY += 3
        screen.blit(images['r_knight'], (playerX, playerY))

    if onpress[pygame.K_w] and onpress[pygame.K_a]:
        screen.blit(images['l_knight'], (playerX, playerY))

    if onpress[pygame.K_s] and onpress[pygame.K_a]:
        screen.blit(images['l_knight'], (playerX, playerY))

    if onpress[pygame.K_w] and onpress[pygame.K_d]:
        screen.blit(images['r_knight'], (playerX, playerY))

    if onpress[pygame.K_s] and onpress[pygame.K_d]:
        screen.blit(images['r_knight'], (playerX, playerY))

    if playerX <= -8:
        playerX = -8
    elif playerX >= 965:
        playerX = 965

    if playerY <= 5:
        playerY = 5
    elif playerY >= 440:
        playerY = 440
    
    for enemy in enemy_list:
        enemy.move()

    for enemy in enemy_list:
        enemy.draw()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    clock.tick(fps)
    pygame.display.update()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIFHa.png)

Comment: Are you asking on how you should code this, or what should the logic be?

Comment: @Vaillancourt How to code it.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried using a range of x and y values but it teleported all of the zombies to that range and it didn't work with their respective locations.

Comment: Well then maybe that should be in your question, rather than asking us to recode some of what you already did.

Comment: your `Enemy.move()` is useless - it send `speed` but it doesn't use it to change position - line `self.x = speed * sin(angle)` `self.y = speed * cos(angle)`. It would be simpler if you would use `pygame.Rect()` with `pygame.math`. And if you want to walk to some target then you should sent this target `self.target_x`, `self.target_y`, calculate ange between currenct position and `target` and use it in `move()` in every loop.

Comment: BTW: you don't need function `enemy()` because you have the same in `Enemy.draw()`. And you could create similar class `Player` instead of separated variables and function `player()`. Shortly: `Enemy` and `Player` could have similar code.

Comment: there is good rule to put all classes and function directly after import - before `pygame.init()`. It makes code more readable. See more in [PEP 8 -- Style Guidefor Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-008/)